# Errors connecting to solrcloud using CloudSolrClient

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm trying to connect to solrCloud using solrj CloudSolrClient, but am getting errors.

Used to directly call a single solr node, now switching to solrcloud. I have tried various different url formats as specified from documentation online.

```
SolrClient solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkUrl).build();
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.setRequestHandler(FIELD_LIST_HANDLER);
QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
req.setBasicAuthCredentials(zkUser, zkPassword);
QueryResponse response = req.process(solrClient, core);
```

When using the following zkHost strings I get the various errors.

host:2181

> 2019-08-21 15:53:17 - ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.a.d.n.s.JerseyConfiguration] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [com.att.dplr.nextgen.search.JerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't init
>   ialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [host:2181], down?)] with root cause
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: host:2181/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=javabin&version=2

http://host:2181

> 2019-08-21 15:55:53 - ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.a.d.n.s.JerseyConfiguration] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [com.att.dplr.nextgen.search.JerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't init
>   ialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [http://host:2181], down?)] with root cause
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: host:2181 failed to respond
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)

host:2181/solr

> 2019-08-21 16:00:11 - ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.a.d.n.s.JerseyConfiguration] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [com.att.dplr.nextgen.search.JerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't init
>   ialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [host:2181/solr], down?)] with root cause
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: host:2181/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=javabin&version=2
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)

http://host:2181/solr

> 2019-08-21 15:57:23 - ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.a.d.n.s.JerseyConfiguration] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [com.att.dplr.nextgen.search.JerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't init
>   ialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [http://host:2181/solr], down?)] with root cause
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: host:2181 failed to respond
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)

What do I need to change to successfully query solr through zookeeper using solrj CloudSolrClient?

I have successfully communicated with the zookeeper instance from terminal.

```
$ echo stat | nc host 2181
Zookeeper version: 3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
Clients:
 /130.10.31.81:60381[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
 /135.40.74.31:48984[1](queued=0,recved=817933,sent=817933)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/80
Received: 1893410
Sent: 1893706
Connections: 2
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0xa00000636
Mode: follower
Node count: 214
```

Comment: How did you configure the zkhost? What are the values for it?

Comment: What is `zkUrl` in the example above? A connection to a zookeeper ensemble should never have `http` in front of it. The `Builder()` example also seems to require different parameters depending on the version of Solr. How you're using it now makes it attempt to connect through http and not through zk.

Comment: @MatsLindh
For my successful `echo stat | nc` command, the zkUrl is just the host (no http)
I had 4 different formats for my zkUrl. When I don't use http, I get the error Couldn't initialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [host:2181], down?)] with root cause org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name. 

I have also tried directly using the ipv4 address and using the zk:// prefix which resulted in zk protocol not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that both solrurls and zkurls can be provided to the `CloudSolrClient.Builder`. I was able to get past the previous issue by using the `SolrClient solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(hosts, Optional.empty()).build();`which accepts zkUrls whereas `CloudSolrClient.Builder(hosts).build()` accepts solr Urls

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation between what is used for solr cloud nodes, and what is used for the zookeeper nodes.  I use zookeeper nodes, and the API docs just were not clear in what they were trying to say.  A little code, like what you provided, made it perfectly clear.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this ClientProtocolException when the configuration itme clusterprops.json was not available in zookeeper /
Contents:

```
{"urlScheme":"https"}
```